# How do I mock a const variable for unit test in C?

Tags: c, unit-testing

Is there any way to unit test a code that depends on constants?

For example:

```c
/*production code*/
const int my_const = 10; // value might be 0 or 10 
int variable = 5; //"reset value"
    
//Tested Function
int foo(){
  if(my_const == 10){
    variable = 2*my_const;
  }
  else{
    variable = 0;
  }
}
    
int main(void){
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

I would like to know if is possible to run a the test case for `my_const = 0` and for `my_const = 10` in the same test, without the need to run more than one.

Comment: `int my_const = 10` defines mutable global variable, not a constant. Btw, better to pass all data to the function as parameters, not via global variables, then it'd be ready for automated testing.

Comment: Yes, the global variables are the problem here.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to inser the const in the exemple. I understand that is better to pass all data as parameters, but I'm working on a legacy code and I'm not allowed to change that.

Answer (score 0):

Having to do some guessing at what you are really after.

- As you did not declare the variable **const** you could just change it: `foo(); my_const = 3; foo();`. You could also pick up values from the command line arguments to make it real easy to run different tests.

  **int const my_const = 10;** should cause fatal compile errors on attempts to change **my_const**. Any that sneak in are implementation specific and might work, confusing your program, abort your program at run time, or anything else. Your tests could verify that a compile error happens but should not test what happens during and after change attempts that sneak past the compiler.

  **int volatile const  my_const = 10;** starts much the same as before but the value could be changed by external agencies. In your case a separate function in a separate compile with just **extern int volatile my_const** could change it.

  - Usually **volatile** is used for values changed by hardware itself in the kernel, drivers, or other out of sight code. It can also be used on values changed by signal handlers.

    It is a "beware" flag to both the compiler and humans that the value is not trustworthy and could change at any unpredictable moment in time.

    Tests would not have restrictions.

    **volatile** is not for causal use and I mention it for education more than anything else. These tests would not have restrictions.

    If used on a variable in the stack you must be very careful it can not be changed after the function returns to corrupt whatever a following call is is now using that space in the stack for.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to unit test a code that depends on constants?

The *constant* in question here is reallly `0` or `10`.  `const int my_const` is not a C constant.

> if is possible to run a the test case for `my_const = 0` and for `my_const = 10` in the same test. without need to run more than one (?)

I'd say no - not for a good test.

Imagine a compiler that takes the `my_const = 0` and puts that object in the same global place as all other objects with default zero initialization.  Same compiler might with `my_const = 10` put the object in a different section of global objects needing non-zero initialization.  Just changing the constant `0` to `10` can significantly impact the object address relative to others let alone its value.  *Interesting* legacy code may depend on address sequencing, values or other ripple effects not easy to discern.

I'd do something like below and pass into the compiler a define for `TEN_OR_ZERO`, perhaps with a default.
Then compile/run, compile/run.

```
#ifndef TEN_OR_ZERO
#define TEN_OR_ZERO 0
#endif
const int my_const = TEN_OR_ZERO;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you probably already noticed, your issue is that you have state outside of the method you want to test.
If you want to be able to write proper unit tests you're going to have to start writing testable code.

in your case, testable code could look like this :

```
int my_const = 10; // value might be 0 or 10 
int variable = 5; // maybe you don't need this.

//Tested Function
int foo(AWellNamedVariable){

  if(AWellNamedVariable== 10){
    return 2*AWellNamedVariable;
  }
  else{
    return 0;
  }
}

int main(void){
  variable = foo(my_const); // an example how you set something outide of the function without introducing state all over the place.
  return 0;
}
```

This is an example of what the code could look like. Other versions can work too. Think about your inputs, think about your outputs